# SQL Derived Table_Duplicate Extract

Tags: sql-server

I am new to `SQL` and have been trying my utmost best to create a derived table within my query and to join with the original table. 
My table is called Claims and there are numerous of columns within the table, however I only need to extract duplicate rows and only certain columns will be the Duplicate Identifier. Thus extracting only certain data within the count query. My issue now is to create a derived table in order to extract the duplicates but keep all the original tables within the Claims Table.

Current query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)AS DUPLICATES_COUNT,
      MbrNo,
      DepNo,
      ServiceDt,
      PracticeNo,
      TarifAmt,
      SchemeCd,
      TariffCd,
      PayAmt,
      Nappi_Cd,
      ChargeAmt,
      RuleCd1
FROM Claims
GROUP BY
      MbrNo,
      DepNo,
      ServiceDt,
      PracticeNo,
      TarifAmt,
      SchemeCd,
      TariffCd,
      PayAmt,
      Nappi_Cd,
      ChargeAmt,
      RuleCd1
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

This provides me with the count and not the data, the derived table will provide me with the data, however there are more columns in the Claims table that is not used in the above mentioned query but must be included within the output.

Please can you assist help me create the query for a derived table?

I truly hope that I am making some sense here, as the terminology is all very new to me.

Thanks 
Chantelle

Comment: What's the PK of your table?

Comment: none of the above can be classified as the PK however in the original table there is a pk record, but based on my required outcome the PK is not necessary, if i understand correctly?? However the it is "Uniqueno''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT *,
           COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY MbrNo,
                                      DepNo,
                                      ServiceDt,
                                      PracticeNo,
                                      TarifAmt,
                                      SchemeCd,
                                      TariffCd,
                                      PayAmt,
                                      Nappi_Cd,
                                      ChargeAmt,
                                      RuleCd1) P
   FROM Claims
) o WHERE P > 1
```

`P` will contain count of duplicates for all rows. Then you filter results by `P > 1`. This is windowing functions, where you can mix raw data with aggregate data.

Comment: Thank you so much, it appears to be working and providing me all the correct info. I am just running some tests on the output to ensure that all data is included. Thanks again for all the help and I hope that one day I can be that proficient in SQL Commands.

Comment: @ChantelleBrink: Just so you are aware: if/when you are positive that someone's answer solves your problem exactly, you can choose to [accept it formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?").